# Unable to mock return value while testing PostConstruct method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to test @PostConstruct method in Spring as follows:

Source file is as follows:

```
@Component
public class XYZProvider {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.class);

    @Autowired
    private Operations operations;

    @PostConstruct
    public void process() {
        try {
            File[] files = operations.process(Constants.DIR); <---IN FILES I AM RECEIVING NULL LIST
            ...
    }
```

Test file is as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class XYZProviderTest {

 @Mock
 Operations operations;

 @InjectMocks
 XYZProvider xyzProvider;

 @Test
 public void test_Success() throws IOException {
   
    when(operations.process(Constants.DIR))
       .thenReturn(getFiles("tests/success"));
   
    xyzProvider.process();

    ...
}
```

In the above code inside test even after mocking return value of `operation.process()`, I am getting null as output while testing the `PostConstruct` process() function. I am clueless regarding how to fix this.

Comment: `when(operations.process(Constants.DIR))` - try to test with `operations.process(Mokito.eq(Constants.DIR))`.

Comment: Still getting null @TassosBassoukos

Comment: what is the return value of the getFiles("tests/success")?